# ASP.NET AJAX CalendarExtender - Problem with Android Browser

Tags: asp.net, css, android, asp.net-ajax, webkit

I'm creating a webapp for Android mobile phones with ASP.NET and the Ajax Control Toolkit.
I've included a CalendarExtender-Control which popups a calendar when focusing the associated Textbox-Control.

If I select this textbox on my mobile phone, the Android webbrowser highlights it with an orange border. The problem is that this border is shown in front of my Calendar popup. Has anybody any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puh...that behavior is done by the Android OS on all input fields. It doesn't depend on your web application and I doubt you have a possibility to disable this behavior, at least for sure not through your web application.

As a workaround, have you tried to use an additional calendar button and make the date picker just pop up if you click on that calendar button? For sure less usable, but it might work.